# Sendgrid API. When sending email with more than 10000 character then starting content of email is appending at last of email

Tags: php, email, curl, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid for quite a long time and it was working fine. But since yesterday when I am sending email with more than 10000 characters then starting part of email is appending at last of email but with less than 10K characters its absolutely fine.

I tested my source code its absolutely fine and even as I said earlier it was working fine. I tested with php mail() method as well and its working fine with mail() method

here is my code for sendgrid api.

```
$from = "bp@xxxxxxxx.com.au";
$headers = 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$ToEmailArray = explode(",",$toEmail);
$json_string = array('to' => $ToEmailArray);
$params = array(
'api_user'  => $user,
'api_key'   => $pass,
'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
'to'        => '',
'subject'   => $subject,
'html'      =>$message,
'from'      => $from
 );
 $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

$session = curl_init($request);

curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// blinding the CV https certificates
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
//$contents['response'] = $response;
curl_close($session);
```

I talk to sendgrid customer support as well but they are saying there is nothing wrong with their API.

Can someone help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "then starting part of email is appending at last of email"?

Comment: sendgrid is a paid service, ask them